# Переключение стилей у конкретного div

Tags: angular2

Подскажите как грамотно реализовать следующую задачу:

- На странице имеется **n** блоков (допустим, 100).
- Каждый блок может быть одним из двух цветов (синий и красный).
- Цвета определяются через классы (`.color-blue` и `.color-red` через
  `[ngClass]`).
- Цвет блока можно менять по клику на него.

Была идея с вызовом функции при создании каждого блока и увеличивать массив `boolean`. При клике менять значение по индексу в этом массиве и по этому же значению работала бы `[ngClass]`. Но как блок тогда узнает свой индекс в массиве?

```
@Component({
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class BlockComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  blockArray: boolean[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blockArray = [];
  }

  createBlock(): number {
    this.blockArray.push(false);
    return this.blockArray.length - 1;    
  }
}
```

---

```
<div (click)="blockArray[?] = !blockArray[?]"
     [ngClass]="{'color-blue': !blockArray[?], 'color-red': blockArray[?]}">
  {{createBlock()}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно зачем вы все так усложнили. Давайте представим ситуацию, что у нас есть массив из 100 элементов, которые нужно отрендерить:

```
// в реальности у вас другие данные
public array = Array.from({
    length: 100
});
```

Рендерим в шаблоне через директиву:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array"></div>
```

У вас должен быть предикат для начального цвета, еще до того, как пользователь кликнул на `div`, как пример `isBlue`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of array" [class.color-blue]="item.isBlue" [class.color-red]="!item.isBlue"></div>
```

Как дальше мы можем поступить? Используя обработчик события менять этот предикат и естественным образом Angular будет менять классы:

```
public changeColor(item: any): void {
    item.isBlue = !item.isBlue;
}
```

Вешаем слушатель:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array" (click)="changeColor(item)" [class.color-blue]="item.isBlue" [class.color-red]="!item.isBlue"></div>
```

А допустим у нас нет предиката и все дивы изначально с классом `.color-blue`, но при клике хотим менять на `.color-red` и обратно:

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

public changeColor(node: HTMLElement): void {
    if (node.classList.contains('color-blue')) {
        this.renderer.removeClass(node, 'color-blue');
        this.renderer.addClass(node, 'color-red');
    } else {
        this.renderer.removeClass(node, 'color-red');
        this.renderer.addClass(node, 'color-blue');
    }
}
```

Вешаем слушатель, только теперь параметром передаем `EventTarget`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of array" (click)="changeColor($event.target)" class="color-blue"></div>
```